# What is the BOLT 10 realm byte for testnet and signet DNS node discovery?

Tags: lightning-network, testnet, peer-discovery, signet

[BOLT 10](https://github.com/lightningnetwork/lightning-rfc/blob/master/10-dns-bootstrap.md#query-semantics) describes a node discovery mechanism based on DNS.

The query semantics include a realm byte that is 0 by default (Bitcoin). What is the realm byte for testnet and signet?

This question was originally asked by Sergei Tikhomirov in the comments of this [question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/88305/why-doesnt-lightning-have-dns-bootstrapping).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no realm byte defined for testnet and signet.

At least `lseed.bitcoinstats.com` and `lseed.darosior.ninja` [don't support testnet nor signet](https://github.com/cdecker/lseed/commit/b80ae545e9fa4b70a8216e465ac19a750a5aed9c).